# Want to configure tika parsing to do OCR on PDFs only

Tags: pdf, ocr, apache-tika

I am trying to manipulate the tika configuration file (using tika server) to exclude all documents except PDFs from OCR processing.  I have tried a number of combinations, such as excluding OCR from the default parser but configuring the PDF parser to do inline processing.  I tried configuring the auto strategy.  I excluded both PDF and Tesseract from the default parser.  No luck.  I ended up running two tika instances, one with OCR configured, and one without it, and directing files based on extension to one or the other in my code.  I am using the python tika client.  Is there a better way?  More generally, is there a comprehensive guide to configuring parser parameters in tika?  Most of what I have seen has been fragmentary.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Did you read http://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/configuring.html and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/PDFParser%20(Apache%20PDFBox) and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the ocrStrategy?

```
pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(ocrStrategy)
```

Where ocrStrategy is an enum - [OCRStrategy](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.OCR_STRATEGY.html)

you can set the value OCR_ONLY for pdf
and NO_OCR for other docs

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I understand how to do it in Java land.  I am using python, and relying on the contents of the tika config file.  I can find no documentation that shows a mapping between that file and the java configuration settings- not sure there is such a mapping.

Comment: I ve no clue how yo do it in python, but I can recommend the TikaOCR started as a docker image - I hope that it works for You. The Tika exposes the rest api and then you can use it and it language agnostic. Look at the blog post explaining how it works: https://medium.com/@masreis/text-extraction-and-ocr-with-apache-tika-302464895e5f

sample command to ocr the scanned pdf is:
curl -H "X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages: true" -H "X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy: OCR_ONLY" -T test.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika